# My IF statement isn't working in an Excel document already stored but when I try it in a blank document it works

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a cell with a drop-down list of 3 entries.  In another cell I have written an IF statement where for two of the entries in the drop-down list I want it to leave the cell blank but if the third entry is selected then it should specify some text.

My IF statement is as follows:-

```
=IF(A8="MSN1","Please pay from GBP Account 800045","")
```

Any ideas why this is working in a new blank document but not in my saved excel spreadsheet?

Comment: What is the result of the formula in saved Excel spreadsheet? In addition to the calculation mode of the formula as r2d3 siad, please also check the format of the cell.

Comment: Please describe "not working". What is the behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Check your calculation mode setting (automatic, manual) in your saved excel spreadsheet. If hitting F9 solves the problem you are in manual mode.

Answer (score 0):

Pls check if the cell is formatted as a "text". It would be good if you can specify the output and the solutions that you have already tried.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.